# Webpack: include html partial inside another partial?

Tags: webpack, partial, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-html-loader

Is there a way to include html partial inside another partial using webpack?
I am using html-loader to do this:

**index.html**

```
<%= require('html-loader!./partials/_header.html') %>
```

But when I try to include another partial inside a   _header.html it is not able to render it.

This is not working:

**_header.html**

```
<%= require('html-loader!./partials/_nav.html') %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was combining a little and I was able to find a solution.

**index.html**

```
<%= require('html-loader?root=.&minimize=true&interpolate!./partials/_header.html') %>
```

and then in **_header.html**

```
${require('html-loader?root=.!../partials/_nav.html')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `html-loader` with `interpolate` option.

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader#interpolation

```js
{ test: /\.(html)$/,
  include: path.join(__dirname, 'src/views'),
  use: {
    loader: 'html-loader',
    options: {
      interpolate: true
    }
  }
}
```

And then in html pages you can import partials html and javascript variables.

```html
<!-- Importing top <head> section -->
${require('./partials/top.html')}
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Importing navbar -->
  ${require('./partials/nav.html')}
  <!-- Importing variable from javascript file -->
  <h1>${require('../js/html-variables.js').hello}</h1>
  <!-- Importing footer -->
  ${require('./partials/footer.html')}
</body>
</html>
```

`html-variables.js` looks like this:

```js
const hello = 'Hello!';
const bye = 'Bye!';

export {hello, bye}
```

You can also include partials inside another partial the same way, using `${require('path/to/your/partial.html')`.

The only downside is that you can't import other variables from `HtmlWebpackPlugin` like this `<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %>` (at least I can't find a way to import them), just write the title in your html or use a separate javascript file for handle variables if needed.

Comment: You know what I dislike here, when using this approach in a multi-page-app:
You have to repeat yourself. In every page you have to require top,nav and footer.
Instead of having a single layout page which includes them all and you just import the body and everything else you need for this page.

Comment: @Legends I don't use html-loader anymore, there are better way to deal with this problem. For example I made this [static site generator with webpack](https://github.com/pldg/learn-webpack/tree/master/static-site-generator) (I also have an updated version, when I've time I'll upload it)